# Could FTP be used to host KML for overlay via maps API?

Tags: google-maps, ftp, overlay, kml

The Google Maps API states that the KML(or KMZ) file can be hosted on a publicly accessible web server.  This does infer that the document should be available via HTTP(S), but the protocol is not actually stated.  Can you please confirm whether the protocol must be HTTP / HTTPS, or could FTP be used as an interim option during the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Cant confirm but if they say that your KMZ can be hosted on a publicly accessible **web server** then it mean **HTTP(S)** and **not FTP**. Can you setup your FTP location to also be accessed via a URL?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, I've just been asked this question by a client. I suspect they have an ftp server accessible to the public but not an http server.

Comment: If they map the FTP server's folder to HTTP also then it should solve the problem, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter a ftp url into the maps search box

```
We could not understand the location ftp://test...
```

suggests they dont understand ftp urls. If it understood the url, it would be a 'cant read file at ... '

Google Maps and the API use the same system for KML rendering.